# Error when deploying contract to Mainnet but not Testnet

Tags: contract-development, mainnet

I built and have tested a contract on the Ropsten testnet but when I tried to deploy to the mainnet the transaction was reverted. not sure what the reasoning was I tried not spending all that much to deploy it so not sure if that was cause or not.

Using Remix IDE for deployment.

Transaction ID: 0x47bbe74d09559298b973348b7c41b4363977ccaea5ad33ced5904c16f5fffaeb

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47bbe74d09559298b973348b7c41b4363977ccaea5ad33ced5904c16f5fffaeb

Fail with:

> A Status code indicating if the top-level call succeeded or failed
> (applicable for Post BYZANTIUM blocks only)

Comment: How big is that contract, how are u trying to deploy it ? Truffle or remix or something else?

Comment: @MajdTL it is a pretty chunky contract about 450 lines and using remix to deploy

Comment: Is that transaction id from the main net? I can’t find it on etherscan

Comment: @MajdTL oops sorry I pasted the wrong TRX_ID 0x47bbe74d09559298b973348b7c41b4363977ccaea5ad33ced5904c16f5fffaeb is the correct one

Comment: @MajdTL I'm unsure what that means

Comment: me 2, I just added it to the question, just in case that some lazy developer dont want to go to etherscan

Comment: you sent some ether (60Wei) with the contract... was that a mistake? that is no the transaction fee.

Comment: hmmm didn't know I did that. I thought that was the gas for the transaction. still pretty new with the ethereum gas and fees stuff

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Probably it is the mistake, but I'm not sure: You have sent extra 60 wei with your contract. that(see the picture) is no the transaction fee and it should always be 0 unless your contract expecting the ether.
If you are using metamask with remix then you can change the gas price there.

Secondly, I guess your gas limit is too low (550,000), take care of sending a transaction with low gas limit, because it will fail. Can you post the transaction id of the contract on Ropston to see how much gas was needed?

I really don't encourage you to deploy anything to the mainnet just for testing, unless you have a product and need a last test, before going live.

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x65b94a197e8814c19edb8f172f6aed6866a6d60f is the testnet contract

Comment: like i said before I am still unfamiliar with the fees side of Ethereum

Comment: that contract needed 4228536 gas to be deployed, you should set the gas limit to more than that (maybe a littel more depends on the version of solidity and optimization number) in remix before sending it. it will probably cost you your rent to deploy it on the mainnet.

Comment: you can see how much gas the contract used in the contract creation transaction
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1b4222e0bc3401d704ba4cbf415158e780cab2404b1d05abb1e548f3c6b0c3f4

Comment: https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php you can calculate how much it  will cost here